# Unable to import dependencies to Gradle using Kotlin - CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am unable to add the library for the Builder class, I am pressing Alt + Enter to import but nothing works. I've also tried importing it manually "androidx.test.runner:runner:1.5.2@aar" but it doesn't stick, tried restarting android studio. Here is the Documentation I'm following: https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camerax/preview

```
fun bindPreview(cameraProvider : ProcessCameraProvider) {
    var preview : Preview = Preview.Builder()
        .build()

    var cameraSelector : CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build()

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider())



    var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
}
```

My Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    val camerax_version = "1.4.0-alpha04"
    // The following line is optional, as the core library is included indirectly by camera-camera2
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}")
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}")
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX VideoCapture library
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}")
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}")
    // If you want to additionally add CameraX ML Kit Vision Integration
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:${camerax_version}")
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
```

Comment: Have you performed the necessary steps and do your set-up meets the minimum requirements mentioned in the CameraX documentation? https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#1

Comment: Im not getting any build error or warnings in the terminal. I can use other CameraX functions. i just cant make an object of the preview, altough Preview works

Comment: I made it work on my other computer just gonna figure out why now^^ same gradle file, imports and android version

Comment: Please never port code as screenshot on stackoverflow.com. Source code is text and it should also be posted as text to make it seachable and copyable.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle is a tool for managing the dependencies, in your case, you can run the gradle build command manually, and check the running log, it will show the detailed info about why the dependency is not downloaded and imported.
the command is like this, with debugging log enabled:

```
gradle build -d
```

Comment: im getting no failures or warnings in when i run a build debug in the terminal, so im guessing all dependancies are added. What is odd is that the library Android studio tries to add androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1" over and over again  and never manages to resolve it for the Preview.Builder() class. i have added it to the gradle file at it build but still i get the same error, tried to create a new project but i get the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

This means your cameraX library did not load in your project. If your android studio is old you must use Jcenter() in gradle allrepo. When you see camerax library download in your project after that import that code.

Comment: I just downloaded Android Studio on this computer, got the hedghog version

Comment: ok you need to add jcenter I show you code where you have to enter this. Go to settings.gradle at the bottom of gradle then you will see this code
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: not doing the trick :/ im kinda new to android studio and i dont understand why its so hard to get the official camerax doc to work out of the box. ive added a new image in the post

Comment: I see the picture dear you still did not loaded library properly. In new android studio version old libraries or java code need some extra things. If you don't follow you cannot solve your issue.